# DB2 64-bit for Windows

Tags: db2, odbc, db2-luw, windows64

Does DB2 comes in 64-bit flavor for Windows environment ? What is the best way to locate installable/executable for the same?

Also, DB2 ODBC Driver I found only 32-bit flavor of it on fix centeral using [this link](https://goo.gl/WrEsZh) . Is there a 64-bit flavor of it available?

I do need one of the above in order for my application running on 64-bit environment to access db2.  Apparently 64-bit processes can not access 32-bit ODBC bridges [ And this whole time I was thinking that world is bigger and better with 64-bit Windows ;-) ].  Is there a work around available in order for above combination to work?

Comment: What I am looking for is a way to access 32 Bit ODBC data source from 64 bit process in Windows Environment !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are drivers for 64 bit available. Try to search specifically for Windows 64 bit drivers. Just as usual on the IBM page its not so easy to find the correct package.. I think with the `DSClients-v105-ntx64-RECOMMENDED` you should get mostly "everything", including the ODBC-driver (see bottom of the screenshot: In `DSClients-v105-ntx64-RECOMMENDED` the `DSClients-ntx64-dsdriver_mm-10.5.700.375-FP007` is included, and that contains `IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC, [..]` - I think this is what you are looking for).

[image: Screenshot of IBM download section]

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Is there a way to use 32 bit ODBC driver with 64 bit processes? I think I am more stuck on that part of the problem.

Comment: @GauravDaga: No, this is not possible. A 32bit application needs the 32bit driver, the 64bit ones need the 64bit driver.